# How to fix 'Cannot use namespace as a type ts(2709)' in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm loading a third-party library called `sorted-array` and using it like this:

```
import SortedArray from 'sorted-array';

export class Selector {
  private mySortedArray!: SortedArray;

  constructor() {
    this.mySortedArray = new SortedArray();
  }
}
```

However, I get this error: `Cannot use namespace 'SortedArray' as a type.ts(2709)`

So, I created this file:

```
// src/typings/sorted-array/index.d.ts
declare module 'sorted-array' {
  class SortedArray {
    constructor(arr: number[]);
    search(element: any): number;
  }
}
```

However, the error remains. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to export it inside module declaration:

```js
declare module 'sorted-array' {
  class SortedArray {
    constructor(arr: number[]);
    search(element: any): number;
  }

  export = SortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Namespaces can be converted to types using the `typeof` keyword.

```
import * as Vector3 from './Vector3'
type Vector3 = typeof Vector3
let foo: Vector3
```

Answer (score 29):

I was struggling to figure out how I could write a type definition for passing an external/3rd party module around. I am very much not wise nor sharp with TypeScript, but [TypeScript 2.9's `import()` syntax](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-9-2/#import-types) seems to be the answer I was looking for (after a long long long long amount of bumbling around, being misdirected):

```
declare type NewRelicModule = typeof import("newrelic");
```

Now I can write my:

```
interface Config {
  newrelic?: NewRelicModule;
}
```

It looks like you are expecting to use the default export. Perhaps for you this might work?

```
declare type SortedArray = typeof import("sorted-array").default;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the type with:

`import { SortedArray } from 'sorted-array';`

Answer (score 0):

You might get this error if what you want to import is a valid interface/type **inside** of a 3rd party namespace.

For example, If your 3rd party library looked like this:

```js
//sorted-array.ts

// namespace that you can't import
export declare namespace sorted-array { 

    // interface that can be imported, but is blocked because it lives in a namespace
   export interface SortedArray { 
      // precious types
   }
}
```

In that case, your declaration can be a little simpler.

```js
// src/typings/sorted-array/index.d.ts

import sorted-array from "/path/to/sorted-array";

export declare type Sorted = sorted-array.SortedArray;
```

And you can use it like this:

```js
import Sorted from 'src/typings/sorted-array/index.d.ts';

export class Selector {
  private mySortedArray!: Sorted;
  ...
}
```