# TypeScript 3: Cannot use namespace 'WordArray' as a type (External module)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to use **simple-crypto-js** lib in my angular app but while installing the package via npm i ... I am getting below Typescript errors - Cannot use namespace 'WordArray' as a type.

Below are the version details:

- Angular 7
- Typescript 3.2
- Simple-crypto-js 2.3

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

ErrorMessage:

```
[16:35:54]  typescript: node_modules/simple-crypto-js/build/SimpleCrypto.d.ts, line: 8 
        Cannot use namespace 'WordArray' as a type. 

   L7:  constructor(secret: string);
   L8:  static generateRandom(length?: number, expectsWordArray?: boolean): string | WordArray;
   L9:  encrypt(data: object | string | number | boolean): string;
```

[16:35:54]  typescript: node_modules/simple-crypto-js/build/SimpleCrypto.d.ts, line: 10
Cannot use namespace 'Encoder' as a type.

```
   L9:  encrypt(data: object | string | number | boolean): string;
  L10:  decrypt(ciphered: string, expectsObject?: boolean, encoder?: Encoder): string | object;
  L11:  encryptObject(object: object): string;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Cannot use namespace as a type ts(2709)' in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853815/how-to-fix-cannot-use-namespace-as-a-type-ts2709-in-typescript)

Comment: @scrappedcola ... Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it is still throwing same error after creating new typing file. I know the error but the problem is how to fix that for a 3rd party module :(

typescript: node_modules/simple-crypto-js/build/SimpleCrypto.d.ts, line: 8 
            Cannot use namespace 'WordArray' as a type.