# Issue importing Type getting Can't use namespace as a type error

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working on creating a common package with TS Types to share across code bases.

I have an NPM package with /src/index.ts exporting my type.

```
export interface CreateCustomer {
    "email": string,
    "firstname": string,
    "lastname": string,
    "entityid"?: string,
    "stage": string
};
```

Building this and publishing it to our local NPM repo.

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "allowUnreachableCode": false,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "ES2021",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": [
          "es2021",
          "DOM"
      ],
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "alwaysStrict": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "inlineSources": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "stripInternal": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "typeRoots": [
          "./node_modules/@types"
      ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/src/*.ts"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@company/common",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "description": "common library ",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-lambda-powertools/logger": "^1.1.0",
    "@aws-lambda-powertools/tracer": "^1.1.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.50.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.108",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "netsuite-rest": "^1.1.0",
    "nsrestlet": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This gives me a file structure

```
company
│
└───common
│   │   package.json
│   │   readme.md
│   │
│   └───dist
│       │   index.js
│       │   index.d.ts
```

Now down stream I'm importing this library into a project like so and trying to use it.

```
import {CreateCustomer} from '@company/common';
let restLet: CreateCustomer= {...}
```

This produces the error

```
Cannot use namespace 'CreateCustomer' as a type.ts(2709)
```

If any one has an idea what I'm screwing up please let me know.

If I change the import to `import {CreateCustomer} from '@company/common/'` the error goes away. From reading documentation on TS it appears that for some reason, likely a stupid one, the interface is getting wrapped up in an extra module/namespace, but for the life of me I can't see it.

Comment: Where is `NsCreateCustomer` defined?

Comment: @Konrad Sorry, typoed the name there. I have fixed it `NsCreateCustomer` was just `CreateCustomer`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Cannot use namespace as a type ts(2709)' in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853815/how-to-fix-cannot-use-namespace-as-a-type-ts2709-in-typescript)

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix my issue as I can't seem to wrap the interface that I want to as a type in a module in my index.ts file.

Comment: To expand on my comment 

I added 
```
declare module 'Cust' {
    interface CreateCustomer {
        "email": string,
        "firstname": string,
        "lastname": string,
        "entityid"?: string,
        "stage": Stage
    }
    export = CreateCustomer;
};
```
To my index.ts file and get the follow error, ` Invalid module name in augmentation, module 'Cust' cannot be found.ts(2664)`

Comment: That answer seems to be for a person with a class that they want as a type. I am only trying to export an Interface like dozen's of examples I have seen on how to create a typescript npm package. I'm also very confuse why use `@company/common/` solves the problem, but I have never had to do that with any third party library.